# Lambda Calculus: Re-Ordering Arguments

Tags: lambda-calculus, algebra

Given any multivariable expression in Lambda Calculus (LC), e.g. for an arbitrary LC expression "op" for some non-commutative operation:

```
E = (\x (\y ( op x y ) ) )
```

Does there exist an LC expression which will transform E into the expression:

```
F = (\y (\x ( op x y ) ) )
```

-?

If so, how can such an expression be generalized such that expressions of any number of variables can be transformed such that arguments are in any desired order?

If an extension to LC is necessary, what options are available?

Citations to literature would be welcome.

Comment: How about $\lambda x \lambda y E y x$?

Comment: This is simply rewriting the expression (i.e. externally to LC operations) to attain an equivalent value, isn't it?  I'd like to know how to derive either my expression F (or perhaps yours) solely by LC applications and abstractions on my expression E above. I'm trying to avoid stipulating an argswap "function", which I believe would be effectively a tree transformation on the AST - an additional layer of abstraction I'm not sure is desirable or necessary.

Comment: The C combinator?

Comment: Looks promising- but what is the equivalent LC expression for the C combinator, and do I then simply apply it to the expression E above?  How would it then be generalized for expressions with any number of arguments?